# How to configure findbugs plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

Can anyone help me to **configure findbugs plugin in eclipse** , so that i can create an xml file and import it and export it as well?? i configured the PMD and CheckStyle plugins by creating  a xml file for both and imported it in eclipse but in findbugs there is no such option of importing files or to configure as well. I tried the option filter files in findbugs but it did not work. If anyone have done it before or know anything about it your suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the same Problem. Actually its really simple.

In Eclipse:

> File -> Export -> General -> Preferences

If you click next you will find several Preferences to export. You will also find Findbugs Preferences.

If you want to import the settings to another Eclipse just use:

> File -> Import -> General -> Preferences and select the exported File ;)

Hope that helps!
Sorry cant post any images because im new here...

Answer (score 5):

You can use a '[filter file](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)'. In eclipse, go to:

> Window --> Preferences --> Java --> FindBugs --> Filter files (tab) --> In *Include filter files* select *Add..*

Then choose your xml configuration file (It may be the one exported from Sonar configuration that Kayser talked about).

Answer (score -4):

In Eclipse go to

```
Help -> Install New Softare 
------>click on Add button
Name-  Find Bug 
Location-  http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse

---------click on OK button
```

Accept the licence key(When u installed u can see licence check box ) and Restart Eclipse

Comment: This question is asking how to configure it with an xml file.